# QJsonDocument::fromJson cannot parse QJsonDocument::toJson QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm using QJsonDocument::toJson to convert a QJsonObject into a QByteArray, and somewhere else in the program, I read that QByteArray and convert it to a QJsonObject using QJsonDocument::fromJson. It doesn't work and I don't know why. QJsonParseError doesn't show anything.

How can I successfully convert to and from QByteArray <--> QJsonObject?

If I run:

```
QJsonDocument doc, doc2;
QJsonParseError jsonerror;
QJsonObject original, copy;

original.insert("foo", 1);
original.insert("bar",2);

doc.setObject(original);
doc2.fromJson(doc.toJson(), &jsonerror);
copy = doc2.object();

qDebug() << doc.toJson();
qDebug() << jsonerror.errorString();
qDebug() << "Null: " << doc2.isNull() << " Object: " << doc2.isObject() << " Array: " << doc2.isArray() << " Empty: " << doc2.isEmpty();
qDebug() << copy.size();
```

I get the following output:

> "{\n    "bar": 2,\n    "foo": 1\n}\n"
>
> "no error occurred"
>
> Null:  true  Object:  false  Array:  false  Empty:  true
>
> 0

I expected the object `copy` to contain the key-value pairs from `original`. It seems like fromJson is not managing to read the result of toJson.

I also tried using the format identifier in toJson to force it to be compact  `doc2.fromJson(doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact), &jsonerror);` and while the output is different, the resulting object is still empty

> "{"bar":2,"foo":1}"
>
> "no error occurred"
>
> Null:  true  Object:  false  Array:  false  Empty:  true
>
> 0

Comment: So if ````doc2```` really is empty, ````copy```` being 0 is no surprise. Does the behaviour change at all when you remove ````copy```` ?

Comment: `fromJson` is a static public member function. You should use it like `doc2 = QJsonDocument::fromJson(doc.toJson(), &jsonerror);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [fromJson is a static member function](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html), so calling `doc2.fromJson(...)` does not change anything inside doc2, instead it constructs a new QJsonDocument and as it has nowhere to go (it is not assigned to anything) it is lost.

This is the example above corrected:

```
QJsonDocument doc;
QJsonParseError jsonerror;
QJsonObject original, copy;

original.insert("foo", 1);
original.insert("bar",2);

doc.setObject(original);
QJsonDocument doc2 = QJsonDocument::fromJson(doc.toJson(), &jsonerror);
copy = doc2.object();

qDebug() << doc.toJson();
qDebug() << jsonerror.errorString();
qDebug() << "Null: " << doc2.isNull() << " Object: " << doc2.isObject() << " Array: " << doc2.isArray() << " Empty: " << doc2.isEmpty();
qDebug() << copy.size();
```

Which generates the output:

> "{\n    "bar": 2,\n    "foo": 1\n}\n"
>
> "no error occurred"
>
> Null:  false  Object:  true  Array:  false  Empty:  false
>
> 2

Comment: Curious design choice, having a regular `````toJson()`````, but a `````static fromJson()`````. Wonder what's the rationale behind it, if any.